# Kinect - Detecting when a Human exits the frame

Tags: c#, kinect

So what I'm trying to do is take the Kinect Skeletal Sample and save x amount of photos, only when a human goes by. I have gotten it to work, except once it detects a human it just records x amount of photos even once the person leaves the vision of Kinect. Does anyone know how to make it so that once a person enters it starts recording, and once they leave it stops?

**Variables**

```
   Runtime nui;
    int totalFrames = 0;
    int totalFrames2 = 0;
    int lastFrames = 0;
    int lastFrameWithMotion = 0;
    int stopFrameNumber = 100;
    DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
```

**Entering/Exiting the Frame**

```
 void nui_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.SkeletonFrame;

        int iSkeleton = 0;
        ++totalFrames;
        string bb1 = Convert.ToString(totalFrames);
        //Uri uri1 = new Uri("C:\\Research\\Kinect\\Proposal_Skeleton\\Skeleton_Img" + bb1 + ".png");
        Uri uri1 = new Uri("C:\\temp\\Skeleton_Img" + bb1 + ".png");
        // string file_name_3 = "C:\\Research\\Kinect\\Proposal_Skeleton\\Skeleton_Img" + bb1 + ".png";    // xxx 
        Brush[] brushes = new Brush[6];
        brushes[0] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        brushes[1] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
        brushes[2] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(64, 255, 255));
        brushes[3] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 64));
        brushes[4] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 64, 255));
        brushes[5] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 255));

        skeleton.Children.Clear();
        //byte[] skeletonFrame32 = new byte[(int)(skeleton.Width) * (int)(skeleton.Height) * 4];
        foreach (SkeletonData data in skeletonFrame.Skeletons)
        {
            if (SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked == data.TrackingState)
            {
                // Draw bones
                Brush brush = brushes[iSkeleton % brushes.Length];
                skeleton.Children.Add(getBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointID.HipCenter, JointID.Spine, JointID.ShoulderCenter, JointID.Head));
                skeleton.Children.Add(getBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointID.ShoulderCenter, JointID.ShoulderLeft, JointID.ElbowLeft, JointID.WristLeft, JointID.HandLeft));
                skeleton.Children.Add(getBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointID.ShoulderCenter, JointID.ShoulderRight, JointID.ElbowRight, JointID.WristRight, JointID.HandRight));
                skeleton.Children.Add(getBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointID.HipCenter, JointID.HipLeft, JointID.KneeLeft, JointID.AnkleLeft, JointID.FootLeft));
                skeleton.Children.Add(getBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointID.HipCenter, JointID.HipRight, JointID.KneeRight, JointID.AnkleRight, JointID.FootRight));

                // Draw joints
                // try to add a comment, xxx
                foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
                {
                    Point jointPos = getDisplayPosition(joint);
                    Line jointLine = new Line();
                    jointLine.X1 = jointPos.X - 3;
                    jointLine.X2 = jointLine.X1 + 6;
                    jointLine.Y1 = jointLine.Y2 = jointPos.Y;
                    jointLine.Stroke = jointColors[joint.ID];
                    jointLine.StrokeThickness = 6;
                    skeleton.Children.Add(jointLine);
                }
                //       ExportToPng(uri1, skeleton);
               // SoundPlayerAction Source = "C:/LiamScienceFair/muhaha.wav";
                //SoundPlayer player1 = new SoundPlayer("muhaha.wav")
               //  player1.Play(); 
              // MediaPlayer.
               // axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.mediaCollection.getByName("mediafile");


                nui.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_ColorFrameReady2);



            }


            iSkeleton++;
        } // for each skeleton
    }
```

**Actual Code**

```
    void nui_ColorFrameReady2(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        // 32-bit per pixel, RGBA image  xxx
        PlanarImage Image = e.ImageFrame.Image;
        int deltaFrames = totalFrames - lastFrameWithMotion;
        if (totalFrames2 <= stopFrameNumber & deltaFrames > 300)
        {
            ++totalFrames2;
            string bb1 = Convert.ToString(totalFrames2);
            // string file_name_3 = "C:\\Research\\Kinect\\Proposal\\Depth_Img" + bb1 + ".jpg"; xxx
            string file_name_4 = "C:\\temp\\Video2_Img" + bb1 + ".jpg";
            video.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
                Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, Image.Bits, Image.Width * Image.BytesPerPixel);

            BitmapSource image4 = BitmapSource.Create(
                Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, Image.Bits, Image.Width * Image.BytesPerPixel);
            image4.Save(file_name_4, Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            if (totalFrames2 == stopFrameNumber)
            {
                lastFrameWithMotion = totalFrames;
                stopFrameNumber += 100;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code to detect when a person enters/leaves the frame.  From what you've said, the actual saving of the image (what you posted) works OK.

Comment: Yes, but once someone enters the view of kinect, it starts saving the frames until it hits stopFrameNumber even if the person leaves the view

Comment: How do you detect when someone leaves the view?  Or is that what you want to know how to do?

Comment: Then you should ask that.  Post the code that detects when someone enters the frame, and ask "what's the best method for detecting when someone leaves the frame?".  What you did post was your image saving code, which is working.  You'll get better help if you clearly state the problem you're having and ask simple, straightforward questions.

Comment: I see you made edits, but you still aren't showing the code that detects when someone enters the frame.  Knowing how you do that would be a big help in figuring out how to detect when someone exits.  I assume you're probably using SkeletonFrameReady, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Ok i posted what when the skeleton enters the frame,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this.  Create a bool class variable named SkeletonInFrame and initialize it to false.  Every time SkeletonFrameReady fires, set this bool to true.  When you process a color frame, only process if this variable is true.  Then after you process a color frame, set the variable to false.  This should help you stop processing frame when you are no longer receiving skeleton events.

Comment: i tried this and then it said that SkeletonFrameReady is not a valid method, any help there?

Comment: I was giving you pseudocode.  In your code you call it nui_SkeletonFrameReady()

Comment: i know, its still saying that

Comment: For some reason the bool it would freeze everytime it saw someone, but i changed it to a int that is always set to 0 unless person is detected, ended up working :/

Answer (score 3):

In most setups I have used in the skeletal tracking event area there is a check for if (skeleton != null) all you need to do is reset your trigger once a null skeleton is received.

The SDK will send a skeleton frame every time the event is fired so...

```
if(skeleton != null)
{
  \\do image taking here
}
else
{
  \\reset image counter
}
```